# Message: refresh token must be passed in or set as part of setAccessToken

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-oauth

We have a problem since some time. We get the error :

Message: refresh token must be passed in or set as part of setAccessToken
Filename: /var/www/html/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Client.php
Line Number: 332

The program is running well on dev but not in prod, and hasn't change since a long time.

our refresh function :

```
if ($this->googleapi->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
   $this->googleapi->setAccessToken(json_decode($this->dataUserCal->data_token_google, true));
   $token = $this->googleapi->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($this->googleapi->getRefreshToken());
   $this->db->set('data_token_google', json_encode($token));
```

We have checked the account, the code, etc…

Comment: So you are saying that you have verified that `json_decode($this->dataUserCal->data_token_google, true)` in there actually produces the correct, current token - yes?

Comment: Please edit your code and include [example] there is not enough information here to help you we need to know where yo are getting $this->googleapi->getRefreshToken() from.

Comment: In the code of googleapi library, we have :

$this->client = new Google_Client();

public function getRefreshToken(){
    return $this->client->getRefreshToken();
}

but this functions sends a null response, and then function getAccessToken() sends an object with "refresh_token" => null.
In dev, we get "refresh_token" => "1//0cvOXErKvzBckCgYIARAAGAwS…